# Timing belt change on a car about to be scrapped

Tags: timing-belt, renault, clio

I currently drive a Renault Clio III 1.5 dCi that just reached 200.000KM.

At my last checkup, the mechanic told me a timing belt change was necessary, along with a few other minor fixes.

I just bought a new car that will arrive in late August, so spending money on a new timing belt for a car that'll get scrapped in a few months seems silly.

My daily commute is 42km round-trip, 5-6 days a week.
Would you recommend changing the belt anyway or can i keep driving until the new car arrives?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Was this because the mechanic looked at the maintenance interval (time since last belt), or did the mechanic actually look inside a timing cover and see a roached belt?

Comment: If timing belt changes are as expensive in Renault Clios as they are for Honda Accords - ~$1000US - forget it! Just cross your fingers and drive (normally) for the next 3 months/2000 miles.

Comment: Is the belt visually bad or it's just due for the age or mileage?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine: The querent [commented on an answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/88879/timing-belt-change-on-a-car-about-to-be-scrapped#comment152375_88880) that it's just "regular maintenance".

Comment: Carry a bicycle in the back as insurance against stranding.

Comment: I see you've decided not to change the timing belt. The right choice in my opinion. If you stay low in revs, I'd expect you'll be fine. In fact, I've heard of someone driving a Peugeot 206 for 554.000 KM's on the original timing belt without ever changing it. It's a Dutch article but in case you're interested: https://www.autoweek.nl/autotests/artikel/peugeot-206-1-4-xs-2001-554-482-km-klokje-rond/

Comment: I find "timing belt" is a blanket recommendation. IOW, they just say that like half the time.

Comment: BTW, I _did_ change the timing belt in an older low-mileage Accord after 8 years.  The dealer had been telling me for 2 years that the expected lifetime was 7 years and the rubber would break down from time-in-service and that if it broke it would of course destroy the engine.  So, $1200 later it was done.  I had asked for the timing belt they removed to be given to me so I could see what an old decrepit thing I had had in there endangering my engine.  They gave it to me in a nice plastic baggie.  It was indistinguishable from the brand new timing belts on display in the parts department.

Comment: New car delivered, old car did almost 1500KM without issues. Thanks for the recommendations

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The change interval is either 5 years or 120.000km, whatever is reached first. Except for engine codes K9K766 and K9K770, where the interval is 5 years or 160.000km.

Now, the interval just "guarantees" that the timing belt will not fail within that time. It does **not** guarantee that the timing belt will fail if you miss the interval!

I would not change the timing belt. You'll be driving like 2.500km, which is about 2% of the change interval.

And, don't forget that there are other components which could fail. Spending maybe 400-500€ for the timing belt will make you feel foolish if the fuel pump fails a week later.

Luckily, you have a Diesel model, so you're safe from the usual trouble with the ignition coils. Instead, the injectors can fail. And if you have had occasional trouble starting the engine, expect the high-pressure pump to fail soon. If that happens, just spend your saved 500€ on an older used car which will last until late August.

Comment: Thank you, i have decided to not replace the timing belt and pray it survives until late august.

Answer (score 18):

The engine in your Renault is more than likely an interference engine. What this means is, if something were to happen to the belt, the engine will be history. This would leave you stranded, more than likely at the most inopportune time. Do you have a backup plan in case the car decides to have an issue because of the timing belt? If not, you should probably get the belt changed.

Did the mechanic state whether there was an actual issue with the belt or did they say this was a "regular maintenance item"? If there's a problem with the belt, you probably would want to change it out so the vehicle will last you until your new car arrives. If it's just a maintenance item, it will probably last you.

Is the car actually going to be scrapped? I mean, will you be sending it to the breakers (wrecking yard) and letting them have their way with it? If so, I doubt I'd change out the timing belt. If you are going to sell the car to someone, then I'd suggest to go ahead and change out the belt, because this would be a selling point which can garner you more money in a sale.

Comment: No he just said it's regular maintenance, and yes i believe the car will be scrapped since i got incentives from the govt for buying a MHEV and scrapping this one.